# Extending primary partition that is blocked by an adjacent recovery partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

My laptop has 2 physical disks and has been upgraded from Windows 7 -> 8 -> 10. Along the way it seems to have picked up several recovery partitions on disk 0.

Disk 0 was originally partitioned into a C (OS) and D (data) drive and C has now filled. So I deleted D with the intent of using its 121GB to extend C. But the 350MB recovery partition between them won't allow this to happen and can't be deleted via Disk Management.

[image]

1. How can I extend C using the unallocated 121GB?
2. If this involves deleting the 350MB recovery partition

   1. How do I delete it?
   2. Is it safe to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that directly with the Windows Disk Manangement. You will need to run 3rd party to do that.

PartitionWizard can do this: https://www.partitionwizard.com/help/extend-partition.html

With this tool you can resize and move partitions.

Reference: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2935022/extend-volume-blocked-recovery-partition-move-partitions.html

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out.

Using `DiskPart` (which comes with Windows). Select the partition that I want to delete and choose `delete partition override`. The override is necessary because it is a protected partition.

Then I used  Disk Manager to extend the C drive partition.

So far I don't appear to have broken anything.

Comment: Just to add a few notes to this solution:  DiskPart.exe is a DOS app but it runs a CLI so you can just double click it to run. Type LIST DISK to show the disks available. The partition I needed to delete was on disk 0, so: SELECT DISK 0. Type: LIST PARTITION. Find the one you want to delete and select it: SELECT PARTITION 6. Then run the delete command: DELETE PARTITION OVERRIDE